# AHK script does not trigger rightclick screen

Tags: autohotkey

I have the following script:

```
#p::
 MouseMove, -300, 300, 10, R
 Click, 100 200 Right
 Send {2}{Enter}
 Return
```

It should move to a certain location, perform a right click and then select the second item. It does however not seem to work. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Which AHK version do you use?
According to 4th example in [v2 documentation](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v2/lib/Click.htm#Examples), WhichButton parameter should be string, so in your case it would be "Right" instead of Right.

In the [MouseClick parameters](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v2/lib/MouseClick.htm#Parameters), WhichButton is specified to be type of string. That wasn't the case in v1.